# Does Geary support Right-to-Left?

Tags: mail-user-agent, right-to-left

I wanted to use Geary as my mail client instead of Thunderbird.

But I don't know if it supports Right-to-Left text!

(I want to be able to write languages like Persian, Arabic, Hebrew etc)

Comment: Geary 0.11 saw a number of improvements for RTL support, and the next releases have more support coming, so perhaps try it out again? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't support `RTL`, anyway i don't know you would like to migrate to `geary` , But i test it and it's very poor. You can use `evolution` or i suggest you stay in `thunderbird`.

Comment: Why?! The latest version is very beauty and full-compatibility with Gnome 3: http://download.gnome.org/sources/geary/0.7/geary-0.7.0.tar.xz I also want to know about RTLing? Hope to be supported :)

Comment: i don't recall  milestone of my geary.so sorry...